# T-SQL format output of int value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to print int value in custom format:
for example int 9888222 should be printed as '> 9.888.222'.

So, rules of output are:

1. Insert '.' after every 3 digits. Starting from the end of the number of cause.
2. Add '> ' string in the beginning of the output string.

More examples:

- 7000 -> '> 7.000'
- 722333 -> '> 722.333'
- 8223344 -> '> 8.223.344'
- 120200300 -> '> 120.200.300'

No values bigger than int maximum value.

Is it possible at all? What functions can be used?

Comment: This kind of thing should be done in the presentation layer, not the data access layer. Do it in the application that will display the value, not in SQL.

Comment: Oded, I`d like to, but i can`t do any changes in BL layer. And this values should actually be inserted into database that way: 9888222 and '> 9.888.222' in one line.

Comment: If your data is displayed as a number, you might not even be able to change it under the stored procedure

Comment: What are the rules of your format? It's usually a good idea to mention whether your output is of fixed length, and display more than one input and output so we can gather how certain corner cases should be handled. Is it just thousands separators you're trying to do?

Comment: Bridge, provided more information.

Comment: So, from the end, insert a `.` before every three digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @INT INT = 120200300 
 SELECT '> ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(@INT AS MONEY),1),'.00',''),',','.')
```